# Python 3.8.3 "File-not-found" message

Tags: python, file-not-found

I am currently studying the book "Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn, Keras and TensorFlow". I tried running the following example, without success however. The link is working, pandas is installed correctly, os, tarfile and urllib are system packages. Still, I get the error message below (tried Jupyter & Spyder):

```
import os 
import tarfile 
import urllib 
import pandas as pd 

DOWNLOAD_ROOT = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ageron/handson-ml2/master/"
HOUSING_PATH = os.path.join("datasets", "housing")
HOUSING_URL = DOWNLOAD_ROOT + "datasets/housing/housing.tgz"

def fetch_housing_data(housing_url = HOUSING_URL, housing_path = HOUSING_PATH): 
    os.makedirs(housing_path, exist_ok = True)
    tgz_path = os.path.join(housing_path, "housing.tgz") 
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(housing_url, tgz_path) 
    housing_tgz = tarfile.open(tgz_path) 
    housing_tgz.extractall(path = housing_path) 
    housing_tgz.close()
    


def load_housing_data(housing_path = HOUSING_PATH): 
    csv_path = os.path.join(housing_path, "housing.csv") 
    return pd.read_csv(csv_path)

housing = load_housing_data()
print(housing)
```

Error message in Jupyter:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 21     return pd.read_csv(csv_path)
> 22
> ---> 23 housing = load_housing_data()
> 24 housing.head()
>
> in load_housing_data(housing_path)
> 19 def load_housing_data(housing_path = HOUSING_PATH):
> 20     csv_path = os.path.join(housing_path, "housing.csv")
> ---> 21     return pd.read_csv(csv_path)
> 22
> 23 housing = load_housing_data()
>
> ~\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in
> read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col,
> usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters,
> true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter,
> nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose,
> skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col,
> date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression,
> thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote,
> escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines,
> warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map,
> float_precision)
> 684     )
> 685
> --> 686     return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
> 687
> 688
>
> ~\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in
> _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
> 450
> 451     # Create the parser.
> --> 452     parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
> 453
> 454     if chunksize or iterator:
>
> ~\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in **init**(self,
> f, engine, **kwds)
> 934             self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
> 935
> --> 936         self._make_engine(self.engine)
> 937
> 938     def close(self):
>
> ~\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in
> _make_engine(self, engine)    1166     def _make_engine(self, engine="c"):    1167         if engine == "c":
> -> 1168             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)    1169         else:    1170             if engine == "python":
>
> ~\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in **init**(self,
> src, **kwds)    1996         kwds["usecols"] = self.usecols    1997
> -> 1998         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)    1999         self.unnamed_cols = self._reader.unnamed_cols    2000
>
> pandas_libs\parsers.pyx in
> pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.**cinit**()
>
> pandas_libs\parsers.pyx in
> pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source()
>
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> 'datasets\housing\housing.csv'

I would appreciate if someone took the time to reproduce/provide input whether the code returns the error message.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The local file `"datasets/housing/housing.csv"` is created only when you call

```
fetch_housing_data()
```

Your code sample does not call this function. Try adding this line before `housing = load_housing_data()`.

Comment: Many thanks for the fast reply! Now it works as expected.. As you probably notice, I am still a Python lightweight, so I cannot even pretend it was a mistake out of distraction.